# Create active admin input dropdown using words array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How do I create a custom input field in Active admin?

This is for an input field gender, which would contain ["Male","Female"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
form do |f|
  f.input :gender, collection: ["Male", "Female"]
  ..
end
```

Comment: Hi Santosh,  by doing this i should manually include the rest of the Attributes in the input field right? Is there anyway to accomplish this without manually inputting the rest of the attributes?

Comment: Any thoughts regarding my comment above?

Comment: When you add a form block, you are overriding the default form. As far as I know, you cannot override specific input fields.